# Firestore thinks I'm offline even when I'm not

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to configure Google Login for my app with Firebase. I'm using `signInWithPopup` for the Auth Flow. On successful login, if it's a new user, I want to set a new document in Firestore and create a new item in DynamoDB.

```
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider) /* ----------------> Creates a user instantly. I verified it in the Firebase Console. */
    .then((value) => {
      const isNewUser = value.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
      if (isNewUser) {
        console.log("This is a new User.")

        const reference = firestore.collection('users').doc(value.user.uid);

        reference.set({ /* ----------------> Doesn't create a document until I disconnect and reconnect my Internet. */
          firstName: "",
          lastName: "",
          emailAddress: value.user.email,
          organisation: "",
          designation: "",
        })

        putTasks(value.user.uid, []) /* ----------------> Creates a new Document in DynamoDB instantly. */
```

As soon as the user logs in, a new User is created in the Firebase Console. A new document is also created in DynamoDB. But, a new document for the User is not created on the Firestore server until I disconnect and reconnect my internet connection. I have not enabled persistence. For some reason, firestore thinks I'm offline even when I'm not.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Can you add some details like: what kind of app is it mobile, web?  what is `putTasks` is there any reference to this? what is `user.uid`?

Comment: @vitooh It is a web app that I'm using React to build. `putTasks` is an axios call to dynamoDB where I put an empty document for further use. `value.user.uid` is the unique user ID generated by Firebase for a new user. My issue is that the `signInWithPopup` creates a user correctly in Firebase, the `putTasks` creates the document in DynamoDB correctly, only the piece of code in the middle, `reference.set` where I set data into Firestore does not work until i disconnect and reconnect my internet.

Comment: It seems that it should work, maybe it's a matter of testing... how do you checking that document is created on "disconnect and reconnect"?

Comment: @vitooh I keep the Firestore console open on screen and make sure that no new document has been created. Then when I simply disconnect and reconnect the internet on my system, the update on the firestore backend is triggered immediately and the new document instantly reflects in the firestore console. Note that this only happens with firestore and dynamoDB and firebase auth trigger instantly like they're supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

This error is quite strange, however I think I can give you a hint. This might be related with the fact that `set` [method is asynchronous](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) and you are not waiting for it. Maybe this action is cached somehow. If I were in your shoes I would use some simple `then/catch` to have eventual errors like this:

```
 reference.set({ /* ----------------> Doesn't create a document until I disconnect and reconnect my Internet. */
          firstName: "",
          lastName: "",
          emailAddress: value.user.email,
          organisation: "",
          designation: "",
        }).then(() => {}, error => {
            console.error(error);
        }
```

Now the code will wait for result and give eventual error. Unfortunately I do not know, if this will solve the issue as I do not have it replicated, but maybe you will be able to go further in the troubleshooting.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the hint, but I did try using a `then/catch` block to check for errors. It passes through the then block normally. I read in some Firestore docs that this is normal behaviour for Firestore when it thinks you're offline. It does not interrupt your code and just updates the backend Firestore server once the connection is restored. Also, it did not throw any errors in the `catch` block.